# Getting incomplete output in netstat

Tags: netstat

Apache tomcat is running on port 8080, but `netstat -tlnp` does not show it, instead its output gets truncated with a binary character:

```
# netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1422/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      829/smbd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      962/dnsmasq         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1097/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5584/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2812          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      829/smbd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1334/nrpe           
�root@server:~#
```

When checking with `lsof` get to know the running process:

```
# lsof -n -i tcp:8080
COMMAND PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    959 tomcat   47u  IPv6  15556      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

And this is how it was started:

```
# cat /proc/959/cmdline
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager-Djava.awt.headless=true-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources-Xms512M-Xmx1024M-server-XX:+UseParallelGC-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed-classpath/opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar-Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat-Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temporg.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrapstart
```

Distribution is Ubuntu 14.04 and netstat version is:

```
# netstat -V
net-tools 1.60
netstat 1.42 (2001-04-15)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `-W` flag to disable addresses truncation?

Comment: Tried it now, got this:

    # netstat -W
    /bin/scnetstat: unrecognized option: W

Comment: pipe the output through `cat -e` to escape any bizarre characters.

Comment: Get this: 

    # netstat -tlnp | cat -e
    Active Internet connections (only servers)$
    ...
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1334/nrpe           $
    M-^?root@server:~#

The mystery remains!

Comment: You could try prefixing the command with `strace -x -s 999 -e write -o /tmp/out ` and so get the strings being written in the tmp file, with hex for the non-printable. You may need to remove the `-e write` to dump more system calls and their strings.

Comment: meuh, sorry for the late response. With strace without -e option also was unable to find a clue. Here is the output of the last write call, followed by two lines of output:

~~~~
writev(1, [{"\xff", 1}, {NULL, 0}], 2)  = 1
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
~~~~

I tried searching for 8080 (the port the service is running on) and 959 (the pid of the process) in the output, but did not get anything.
It seems like netstat is aborting before getting to the end..

Can upload the complete output if you think its relevant.